# Problem deploying a project that uses Intel Parallel studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, deployment, parallel-processing, openmp

So I have this small application of mine I'm trying to deploy using visual studio. I have `Intel parallel studio 2011` added to visual studio, and I'm compiling this program using Intel within VS because I'm using OpenMP task construct which is not supported in VS2010.  I added a deployment project to my solution and built a setup. Dependencies are detected as follows:

```
glu32.dll opengl32.dll and libiomp5md.dll
```

Now I'm trying to test this setup file to see if it works. I have Windows XP Mode installed and I access the setup file, I setup my application, decencies are copied just fine but:
When I try to run the application first time I got an error saying:

```
The entry point _ftol2 could not be loacted in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll
```

I found solution to this problem by removing glu32.dll and opengl32.dll and adding glut32.dll to my windows/system folder.
But then it comes up with this second error saying:

```
The application or dll ".....\libiomp5md.dll" is not a valid windows image. please check this against your installation diskette
```

again I googled and I got [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919753) and it didn't work.

Reminder: I'm using Win7 x64 and Visual Studio 2010 with Intel Parallel Studio 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to install the [redistributable libraries](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-of-the-intel-c-and-fortran-compiler-for-windows/) on the target machine.

Comment: sorry, it took a while, thought accepting as answer would give you the bounty too, thanks